# I am the joint recipient of an award (along with an unrelated person). Should I name them on my resume?

Tags: undergraduate, awards

I recently received a prestigious award from my university for my undergraduate research (of which I am quite proud!). The award is always awarded jointly to two people. I have no professional relationship to the other winner (the award was not shared between us because of work we did together or anything of the sort), although she works in a field not very distant from mine, and we are polite acquaintances.

How should I list this on my academic CV? Should I include her name and state that the award was jointly given to the both of us? If so, should I link to her website/include more identifying information about her?

I worry that if I don't include her name it'll seem dishonest (as I will make myself seem like the sole recipient of the award by default, making it seem more prestigious than it is). It simply feels like leaving out information (the description of the award itself makes note more than once that it is always to be given to two people). However, including her name might seem a bit weird since we aren't colleagues in any sense, and it could also give the impression that I'm hoping her achievements will make me look better (she is *much* more well-known and accomplished than I, as would be immediately obvious to anyone who looks her up---I don't say this out of humility).

I am in the US, although I would rather not specify in which field we both work. Any advice for what is standard would be appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you just write something along the lines of "Co-Recipient of XY award", that way you acknowlegde that you haven't been the only one to receive it, but don't have to disclose anything about the unrelate second winner?

Comment: It sounds like you received the award. Just because there are two awards, doesn't mean it was a joint award. There are normally four Fields Medals awarded at a time, but each person is a Fields' Medallist, not a joint one.

Comment: @Sursula-they- I think you could turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Anyon It feels to simple and basic to merit being an answer

Comment: @Sursula-they- Fair enough. I often feel the same way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Echoing DavidA.Craven's comment, this does not appear to be something I would describe as a *joint* award, rather there are two separate awards. "Joint" implies some shared contribution, like if projects were done in pairs and awards were given by the project. In that case, you might reasonably feel compelled to disclose that the award is to a joint project of which you are a member (whether there are 2 contributors or 100) to acknowledge that someone else contributed to you winning the award.

In this case, it seems like an award of the same title is given to two different people, but your work is your own. Nothing that the other person did is relevant to the work that you were awarded for; if they were erased from history, you'd still have the award (and presumably some additional, third person would also have the award).

I would just list the award. If someone is curious enough to search the web for it, they'll possibly see you were one of two people that received it that year (assuming this is the sort of thing that is posted on a department/university web site somewhere); I don't think that will put them off.

Certainly I would not list the other person. You may want to describe what the award is *for* depending on how it is named; e.g. "Best Undergraduate Research Award" is probably fine as it is, but "Pedro Award" in honor of some emeritus professor Pedro could probably use a note indicating the meaning. If you wanted to be completely transparent you could note "one of two recipients" in parentheses.

Congratulations on your achievement!